# Views Regular Expression filter

Tags: 7, views

I am using a view to show content with the name of the node as an exposed filter. None of the operators suites me and I was wondering if I can manage to use Regular Expression Operator for the desired result.

What I want is very similar to "Starts With" operator but the difference I would like to search for EVERY word that Starts with the given value and not the start of the sentence.

Is this possible with Regular Expression operator? What is the actual Regular Expression for that?

Thanks

Comment: Check answer of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36689/views-regex-exclude-alphabetical-strings-as-well-as-those-with-spaces if it suits you..

Comment: @RajeevK OK...Thanks for the link...it clarified to me that views uses mysql regex and not php. I have a naive question though. Where do I put my regex expression in the views UI? I guess is not in the value field right?

Comment: @RajeevK I don't know if I am on the correct path but what I did is used two filters for the name. One that contains the regex and one that is exposed with the "contains" operator.